# Angularjs ng-repeat : how to display an array of object

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display this values of an property inside an json object with ng-repeat.

```
"id_products" : [5730827476402176: 2, 5173045979250688: 1, 5735995932672000: 2]
```

I am using ng-repeat on `<tr>` inside a table. If the property is a simple array I can display without problems but as the object showed above I am just getting [].

This is a snippet of my code:

```js
<tbody>
        <tr class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="item in sales|orderBy: 'name'|filter: filter">
          
          <th> {{item.id_products}}</th>
          
          .....
```

I tried nested ng-repeats but I get the same result.

What is the right way to display this object?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running a ng-repeat inside the ng-repeat on the item and then say "value in item"?

Comment: yes. it is the same thing

Comment: Can I get you to create a fiddler or something the we can try?

Comment: ok. just a few minutes...

Comment: The code you posted (`[5730827476402176: 2, 5173045979250688: 1, 5735995932672000: 2]`) is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: you should have an inner `ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.id_products"`

Comment: @ JB Nizet it is json representation it is not a javascript expression

Comment: Also, the variable names in your ng-repeat statement don't match any of the names of the objects in the example you presented. Please provide your actual code or a codepen/jsfiddle

Comment: I am trying to create a jsfiddle but it seems that this type of object is not valid as an javascript object. I can't see the representation of the actual object in the browser developer tools.

Comment: I will post a jsfiddle soon

Comment: It seems that this kind of object structure is impossible to be displayed by ng-repeat

Comment: It is not valid json either.

Comment: yes you were right, I can see this structure in the browser console but If I want to display it or iterate over it it's not working

Answer (score 0):

see the ng-repeat documentation - "**The built-in filters orderBy and filter do not work with objects, and will throw an error if used with one**.

If you are hitting any of these limitations, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to ngRepeat"

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I didn't tried to use the built in filter but just display it. Anyway I think this type of structure is not allowed because I try to iterate it and display in the console with angular.forEach loop and it is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 0):

This object data structure is not javascript or json valid.